# Python/Django: Print message upon form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

New to Django/Jquery:

Trying to print "Thanks for signing up!" after a form is submitted.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("input[data-submit-item]").live("click", function() {
        var message = "Thanks for signing up!";
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/add",
          data: {
            "text": $("#item").val(),
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $('input[name~="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
          },
          success: function(data) {

            $("#item-list").append(data);
            $("#confmessage").append(message);
            $("#item").val("");
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "main-container">

          <h1>FooBar Baz</h1>
          <div id = 'signup-form'>
            <form>
              <input type="text" id="item" placeholder="Enter your email ..." />
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" data-submit-item="true" /></div>
            </form>
              </div>
   <div id = "confmessage"></div>
                <p><strong>front</strong></p>
  <ul id="item-list">
    {% for item in line %}
      <li>{{ item.text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  <p><strong>back</strong></p>
  <p><a href="/remove">remove</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This just prints out a list of all the entered emails but doesnt print the confirmation message. This is a modification of this example: https://github.com/memcachier/memcachier_line/blob/master/templates/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
$("#confmessage").text(message);
```

instead of using `append`.

Comment: Thanks! but still doesn't print out anything...:(

Comment: Im guessing it has to do with Javascript being asynchronous?...any ideas as to how to ensure that call runs?

Comment: I think your AJAX request is failing (server error, or perhaps 403 from CSRF, if you clear your cookies but don't refresh the page to get a new token in the page)